# How can I correct a blurry viewfinder beyond the built-in adjustment?

Tags: viewfinder, diopter

Over the ages, my eyes are not healthy as I was younger, and now my viewfinder is getting much more blurry. I've adjusted it to adjustment limit. And, it is hard to use my eye glasses, especially when I use manual focus.

Is there is a way to change my viewfinder or readjust it to be suitable for me? Is there is a way to find another viewfinder lens? Is it interchangeable with various lens power?

I have a Nikon camera.

Comment: We might assume you only need simple vision correction. But from recent personal experience I can tell you that an eye exam may warranted. You may have an uncorrectable (without surgery) problem, such as a cataract or even a detached retina. I recommend that you have your eyes checked if you aren't absolutely sure. I just went through this myself, and if I had waited much longer in seeing an ophthalmologist, I might be blind in one eye.

Comment: A quick assumption-check: are the viewfinder eyepiece and the reflex mirror clean?

Comment: yes its clean. the diopter adjustment is on the very right position the last degree in minus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a DSLR (or some higher-end mirrorless camera), you can add an eyepiece accessory to provide additional magnification (or minification, if you need negative adjustment).

The adjustment in your viewfinder is measured in "diopters", just like an eyeglass prescription*, and as you note, the built-in adjustment can only go so far. But you can add additional correction as well with an accessory for most SLRs and at least Fujifilm and Leica mirrorless cameras. See [the selection at B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Eyepiece+Accessory_Diopters&ci=19005&N=4077634559+4111488783) for many options — use the filter on the right to narrow down to the camera and correction you need.

I see in the comments that you are dialing the built-in correction all the way to its maximum minus. Multiple diopters can simply be added together, and the built in probably has a range something like -2 to +2, so if you get a -5, you can then get a total adjusted possibility of -7 to -3, which hopefully will cover what you need.

If this doesn't work for you, another option is a magnifier for the rear LCD screen; this works basically the same way, but since that is inherently larger and more flexible with workable distance from your eye, it may be more convenient if your vision is really reaching the limits.

---

<sub>* for that matter, it also works [just like a supplementary close-up lens on the front of the camera for macro](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59163/how-can-i-calculate-the-effect-of-a-supplementary-close-up-lens-a-k-a-macro-fil) — just applying to the viewfinder rather than to the image through the lens.</sub>

Comment: what I am talking about s Nikon D3200, one more question please. How can I know the power of my installed diopter? and how to know if I need + or - of the new one? I see there are -5 to +5 how could I know if I want to deliver it online without testing it?

Comment: I forgot to say it is not a problem of magnification. The problem in I cant focus the viewfinder, I cant get the view sharper.

Comment: Figure out which way is sharper: towards + or towards -, that will give you the sign.  Find out how much adjustment your camera has built in.  [Nikon](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/639/~/viewfinder-diopter-adjustment).  If maxing out the adjustment gets you close, then buy a lens equivalent to the maxed out adjustment.  If not buy a stronger one.  You can fine tune with the built in adjustment.  The alternative is to buy a lens equivalent to the difference in your glasses prescription from when you could adjust the eyepiece enough.

Comment: @hsawires The blurriness is corrected by either magnification or the opposite — that lets you focus properly. (See [How do add on macro lenses allow you to take macro photos?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59157/how-do-add-on-macro-smartphone-lenses-allow-you-to-take-macro-photos) — it's exactly the same.) Chris's suggestion of matching your eyepiece prescription is a good one. That will at least tell you the direction you need, + or -, and give you an idea of required strength.

Comment: s/eyepiece/eyeglass/. That's a very strange autocorrect error. Or I guess we can just all imagine you wearing a monocle.... :)

Comment: so to make sure what correction I need here in that [link](http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3200/img/compatibility03/parts_and_controls.png) my dial diopter is rotated to the maximum left, that's mean I need more rotation to the left which is the mines ... is that correct mr. @mattdm ?

Comment: @hsawires I'm not absolutely sure that left and right mean the same thing on all camera brands, unfortunately.

Comment: sorry for bothering you. if you can bare me I will describe it more. because I don't have the possibility to try from various diopters. I have to get it online. the left sign printed in white in my dipoter is (-) and I cant rotated more to the left. I mean I can not get more mines. so that's mean I need more rotation to the left? so as you said the [DK-20C -5.0 Correction Eyepiece](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Eyepieces/DK-20C--5.0-Correction-Eyepiece.html) is what I need. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @hsawires I think the easiest way to think about it is as mentioned above, to match your eyeglass prescription. If you're nearsighted, you'll need a negative correction.